# UniqueConstraint hibernate and what is catalog

Tags: java, hibernate, maven

I just want to get explanation for this import, i was searching for some good explanation but unable to find it.

```
javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint
```

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/maven-hibernate-annonation-mysql-example/

i am following this example for hibernate.
everything else i am able to understand. but why we use unique constraints here ?

```
@Table(name = "stock", catalog = "mkyong", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "STOCK_NAME"),
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "STOCK_CODE") })
```

and what is catalog here?

And we have to declare unique in here also?

```
@Column(name = "STOCK_CODE", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 10)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

@UniqueConstraint is going to allow you to specify a unique constraint which spans columns, whereas specifying it in @Column is only for the column.  For flexibility and consistency, some shops/engineers will only use @UniqueConstraint so that there's only one place to look.

While implementation specific, for MySQL believe it's the database name.